# JavaScript function that takes a multidimensional array and a single array, and finds matches of the single array in the multi-d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I tried looking at a similar question in stack overflow but it didn't cater to exactly what I'm trying to do and I keep trying to make it work but continuously get the wrong results. At this point I'm simply at a loss. Example of what I mean

```
var masterArray = [[1,2,5,6],[5,13,7,8],[9,11,13,15],[13,14,15,16],[1,9,11,12]]
var compareArray = [9,11,13,15,1,2,5,6]

function intersect(a, b) {
//code to compare both arrays and find a match
}

console.log(Intersect(compareArray, masterArray))
```

And the output would be

```
[9,11,13,15]
[1,2,5,6]
[5,13]
[13,15]
```

Comment: Show (add to your question) your best effort so far and explain where and why you are stuck.

Comment: Check the output again! I think you forgot one!

Comment: why `[1,9,11]` is not in the final result?

Comment: you have 5 sub arrays to return 4 outputs.. How so..

Comment: Sorry, I missed typing that one, but yes. [1,9,11] would be one of the outputs as well.

Comment: Thank You for the answers. This was my first time using stack and continuously trying to improve my programming skills. I appreciate everyone's input! I was going about it wrong with my code, I was using 3 for loops. 1 was to loop through my single array and the other 2 were used to loop through my multi-d array. Then I was attempting to us an if statement to compare both loop array index and push the matches to a new array **if (x[a] == y[b][c]) { res.push(x[a]) }; but this kept giving me unwanted results. Next time I have a question, I'll be sure to include the code I've done so far as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Array.prototype.reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get an array of all the intersections like this:

```js
var masterArray = [[1,2,5,6],[5,13,7,8],[9,11,13,15],[13,14,15,16],[1,9,11,12]];
var compareArray = [9,11,13,15,1,2,5,6];


function intersect(multi, simple) {
  return multi.reduce(function(res, b) {
    var intersection = simple.reduce(function(r, e) { // get the intersection of the current array and compareArray (simple)
      if(b.indexOf(e) != -1) // if the current element of the current array is also in the compareArray then push it into the intersection array
        r.push(e);
      return r;
    }, []);
    
    res.push(intersection); // push the intersection array into the result array
    return res;
  }, []);
}

console.log(intersect(masterArray, compareArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution using [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object with specific regex pattern(converting `compareArray` numbers into regex alternation group items).
Additional functions used:
`String.prototype.match()`, `Array.prototype.join()`, 
`Array.prototype.map()`

```js
var masterArray = [[1,2,5,6],[5,13,7,8],[9,11,13,15],[13,14,15,16],[1,9,11,12]],
    compareArray = [9,11,13,15,1,2,5,6];

function intersect(compareArray, masterArray) {
    var pattern = new RegExp('\\b(' + compareArray.join('|') + ')\\b', 'g'),
        result = [];

    masterArray.forEach(function(v) {
        var matches = v.join(' ').match(pattern);
        if (matches.length) result.push(matches.map(Number));
    });

    return result;
}

console.log(intersect(compareArray, masterArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your logic, you have wrong output in your question :

```
var masterArray = [[1,2,5,6],[5,13,7,8],[9,11,13,15],[13,14,15,16],[1,9,11,12]]
var compareArray = [9,11,13,15,1,2,5,6]


function intersect(a, b) {
  var temp = [];
   k = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
      temp1 = []
      for(j=0;j<b[i].length;j++){
         if($.inArray(b[i][j], a) > -1){
            temp1.push(b[i][j]);

         }
      }
      temp.push(temp1);
   }
   return temp;
}

console.log(intersect(compareArray, masterArray));
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swapper8/s3p4ks1x/4/).

Give it a try, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this ES6 function:

```js
function intersect(a, b) {
    a = new Set(a); // for faster lookup
    return b.map(c => c.filter(a.has.bind(a))).filter(Boolean);
}
// Demo
const masterArray = [[1,2,5,6],[5,13,7,8],[9,11,13,15],[13,14,15,16],[1,9,11,12]];
const compareArray = [9,11,13,15,1,2,5,6];
console.log(intersect(compareArray, masterArray).join('\n'));
```

The `.filter(Boolean)` part is optional, and only needed to exclude arrays that have no matching numbers at all, which otherwise would be represented by empty arrays in the result.

Using `Set` will improve the performance, as lookup in a `Set` (with `has`) can be done in near-constant time.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the filtered result of the `masterArray`.

```js
var masterArray = [[1, 2, 5, 6], [5, 13, 7, 8], [9, 11, 13, 15], [13, 14, 15, 16], [1, 9, 11, 12]],
    compareArray = [9, 11, 13, 15, 1, 2, 5, 6],
    result = masterArray.map(function (a) {
        return a.filter(function (b) {
            return compareArray.indexOf(b) !== -1;
        });
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6

```js
var masterArray = [[1, 2, 5, 6], [5, 13, 7, 8], [9, 11, 13, 15], [13, 14, 15, 16], [1, 9, 11, 12]],
    compareArray = [9, 11, 13, 15, 1, 2, 5, 6],
    result = masterArray.map(a => a.filter(b => compareArray.includes(b)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```